# How to use TeX Gyre fonts installed by TeX Live

Tags: font, latex

I've installed TeXLive on Mountain Lion. The TeX Live Utility says that the `tex-gyre` package is installed, however these fonts don't appear on my system and I actually get errors when trying to use them with XeLaTeX.
What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the problem, you might get better answers on http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my installation (MacTeX 2012) the fonts seem to be located into `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/`, especially into the "opentype" and "truetype" folders.
If you can't find them, you can try running:

```
locate tex-gyre
```

Once you have located the fonts, to install them just copy them into `~/Library/Fonts` (user-specific) or `/Library/Fonts` (system-wide).